# javascript WYSIWYG HTML editors?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, dhtml

What are the options for something that will let users make text bold/italic/underline/etc as they are writing in a textarea and work in all browsers?

Comment: there are about 50 variations of this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a look to [FKCEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/), I always recommend it...

Comment: the newer CKEditor is a VERY much improved implementation. clean and very modular .. and the code is waaaay more approachable than FCK ever was

Answer (score 4):

I always liked TinyMCE
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Comment: +1 extremely easy to use if you're content with the default configuration, and the only difficult part of using a custom one is reading through all the options.

Answer (score 2):

I favor the Rich Text Editor in the YUI

Answer (score 1):

I've used [InnovaStudio WYSIWYG](http://www.innovastudio.com/editor.asp).  Pretty extensible and cheap.

Answer (score 0):

FCKEditor is a popular choice, although it's incredibly bloated. There's a nice simple example in jQuery [jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/20)

I wrote my own in the end as I wanted to customise the editor quite a lot. It's not too difficult to do and typically involves popping an iframe on the page, setting the contenteditable to be true and then using a simple javascript command to update the html of the iframe.