# Textarea which allows HTML content in Database

Tags: php, html, database, textarea, wysiwyg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript WYSIWYG HTML editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805639/javascript-wysiwyg-html-editors)

Im not quite sure how to put this as i dont know what its called. But essentially what i need is a textarea like the one on stack overflow with a Bold button where you highlight text, or bullet points etc and I have heard there are some good open source ones.

I have a database with php going into it from a plain text area, i just need to be able to do extra features.

Many thanks!

Comment: @Purmou Oh wonderful thank you :) I will have a look at implementing that it looks good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use http://ckeditor.com/ for most things, since you can customize it to meet your demands with relative ease, and dispite many WYSIWYG editors it actually handles the generated HTML quite well.

For the textarea to receive and send off data, you will need to consult the documentation for the WYSIWYG editor you are using, since it varies from editor to editor, how you manipulate, set and get data.

You will need to output the HTML with PHP like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($database_stuff["content"]);
```

Then the otuputted content will not be parsed by the browser (but by the WYSIWYG editor - if parsed at all).

Comment: Very nice thank you very much, I will make this the answer in 8 mins when it lets me :P

Answer (score 2):

From another thread where I posted the same answer:

There are many to choose from. Among the most popular are:

- [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/) - Open Source browser based html5 enabled rich text
  editor.
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) - Open Source browser based rich text editor.
- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) - Open Source editor control.
- [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/) - Open Source XHTML editor focusing on semantic markup.
- [Dijit Editor](http://dojotoolkit.org/) - a Dojo-based rich text editor component.
- [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) - a Yahoo! rich text editor component.
- [KindEditor](http://code.google.com/p/kindeditor/) - Open Source HTML editor.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich-text_editor